# membership.deleteuser() returning false

Tags: asp.net, membership

I am trying to delete an asp.net user from all tables.
When I call:

```
bool isDeleted = Membership.DeleteUser(username, true);
```

`isDeleted` is being set to false;

Is there a way to tell why it is not deleting the user?

Answer (score 2):

I found another reason why the user could not be deleted:
it happens also if you change (in the aspnet_Users) the `UserName` but not the `LoweredUserName` accordingly.
At least this is what happened to me:
as soon that I changed also the `LoweredUserName` I could finally delete the user.

Answer (score 1):

Put a break point on that line of code and press F8 to step into it in debug mode.

Comment: +1 because the only logical thing to do with this much info is to debug.

Comment: You can't step into the Membership.DeleteUser method.

Comment: When the breakpoint hits, check out the value for the username variable to make sure it's not your code.  If you are sending in a valid username then you'll have to contact the provider of that Membership class to see why it's not working.  We don't have enough information to do anything but speculate what's wrong at this point.

Comment: Yes, I am passing in a valid username.  I am using the built in asp.net System.Web.Security Membership class for this.  I wonder why they don't return an fail message vs just "false".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like when you delete membership user, even with deleteAllRelatedData=true

e.g.

`Membership.DeleteUser(UserName.Text, true);`

The user is **NOT** deleted from the dbo.aspnet_Users table which means that user cannot then re-register with the same name again (even though they will will have a different GUID)

I understand this is intended behaviour though it makes no sense to me.

However, the following routine will remove all traces from the aspnet database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASPNET_Member_DELETE_By_Name] 
    @UserNameToDelete nvarchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @UserToDelete nvarchar(255)

    SELECT @UserToDelete = UserID 
    FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = @UserNameToDelete)

    DELETE FROM aspnet_Profile WHERE UserID = @UserToDelete
    DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserID = @UserToDelete
    DELETE FROM aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser WHERE UserID = @UserToDelete
    DELETE FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID = @UserToDelete
    DELETE FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserID = @UserToDelete

    END
```

However, this has limitations if you are using aspnet membership across several applications (as I am)  with the same database - you may have a situation where the same user logs in to multiple applicatiosn with the same user name.

For this scenerio you will need to pass in the application name and determine the application ID for the user prior to performing the delete.

First time I've posted here so be gentle...

Answer (score 0):

The username is probably wrong - either the name doesn't match what's in the database, or the user isn't really in the database.

However, the ApplicationName could be wrong, or you could be pointed at the wrong Membership database by mistake.

The only other possibility that I can see is that you've modified the aspnet_Users_DeleteUser sproc and broke it.

Comment: Greg - all good things to check and all things I have checked.  I didn't touch the sproc either.  Really I wasn't looking for a solution to get it to work here moreso looking to see if there was a way to get a failed message so I could debug.

Comment: There's not much to debug within the framework itself...it's all in the sproc.  I'd suggest opening up the sproc and testing it and breaking it down until you figure out the problem.  It's possible there's an error happening during the sproc that's not being reported. (`@TablesToDeleteFrom` is set to 15 btw)

Comment: I should add that the return value of this method is calculated as "@NumTablesDeletedFrom > 0"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the provider name, it worked for me by sending the username only.

I'm using SharePoint 3.0 with FBA, when a user is removed from SharePoint you can still find it in the FBA database. That's why I use this function as followed:

bool deleteUserResult = Membership.DeleteUser(currentUserLogin, true);
if (!deleteUserResult) throw new Exception("...);

hope this helps,
Damien